# Julia.I decided to test some math in Julia and I got an error

Tags: python-3.x, julia, ijulia-notebook

Here is an expression, check it yourself:

- Julia: `((((9^0.5)^3)^2)^2)/((-2)^(-3))`
- Python: `((((9**0.5)**3)**2)**2)/((-2)**-3)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0SE.png)

Comment: Perhaps it was calculated correctly. But since I'm not used to dots in integers, this is a little alarming, because I just started learning this language.

Comment: 1) Please paste all your code and results as text (you can just edit the question).  Having all in a non-copyable, linked image is kind of annoying for people trying to help. 2) What's the actual error? Maybe give a comparison of expected and actual result.

Comment: Those are the same value.

Comment: Both are same values, but in different format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PyCall to test whether the results are identical. The `py""` string macro will allow you to easily compare results from Python and Julia.

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> py"((((9**0.5)**3)**2)**2)/((-2)**-3)" == ((((9^0.5)^3)^2)^2)/((-2)^(-3))
true
```